# In documentation simple prensent passive or simple future passive?

Tags: grammar

I saw in many documentations that the simple future passive is more used than the normal simple present passive. for example:

- These gained data will be sent to a server for filtering then saved in database and depending on the request sent as response for the interested riders.
- These gained data is sent to a server for filtering then saved in database and depending on the request sent as response for the interested riders.

Which one is more correct?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'll take a chance and say the first one is incorrect due to conjunction-reduction. I do not know but can you reduce ".., will then be saved ..."? It atleast seems wrong/awkward to me. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The future version asserts one's determination to customarily follow a certain course of action.  The present version formulates a procedural rule which is generally followed.  So, which you use just depends on what you mean.  They could mean different things if in the past, standard procedure was different, so that the second meaning was inoperative.